# Custom Form on CMS page

Tags: forms

I tried to find something and googled myself but I couldn´t find anything that fits my needs.

I want to include a custom form with a number of different inputs on a Magento CMS page sending all to an email or to the Magento backend.

So that a user has like 10 different questions to answer and then on the submit button it all sends it to a given email address.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on creating custom forms in Magento. Here is one http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/

Comment: A good alternative is also Google Forms (if you don't want to put your hands in the code)

Comment: You cannot add a form to a CMS page. You can either create a module, add a controller file with an action to render the form and an action to retrieve the data input from the form and save it to your model, and access it via yoursite.com/yourmodule/yourcontroller/form or you can install an extension that does that for you. I've used Webforms extension by mage me: http://mageme.com/ it is really great. It sends emails, you can configure to display fields depending on a certain logic, and the guy behind it offers great support. I really recomend it.

Comment: @Vic you can insert blocks into CMS pages, so technically, yes you can add a form to a CMS page.

Comment: You can even put a form directly into the CMS page itself. The main complexity, I would say, is the backend - which could either be custom, or could be a hosted forms solution.

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad. Haven't had my morning coffee. So the OP would have to still build a module to render this block and an action to handle the data, and then insert the block to the CMS page.  That is actually how the extension Webforms works now that I think of it. It's the OP's choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Google Forms as the person taking over the details is in Marketing and therefore it was the easiest this way.
Thanks for all the comments.

I will have a closer look in the Inchoo Tutorial :-)